# Silverlight Book Suggestion (With Specific Features)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

*(Note: Please do not mark this question as duplicate. This question is based on specific features of Silverlight)*

I am planning to **learn Silverlight**. I have 4 years of **.Net experience** including C#, WCF, ASP.NET.

Which is the best book that `covers the following topics` and easy to learn and deep?

1)  Silverlight architecture and WCF

2)  Dependency Properties

3)  Patterns like PRISM

4)  XAML coding

5)  Silverlight controls

6)  RIA , MVVM

***Note:*** If someone ask me which is my favorite book for C#, I would say it is **“C# in Depth” by John Skeet**. I am looking for a `Silverlight book` having qualities similar to  the above mentioned book.

Thanks

Lijo Cheeran Joseph

Comment: I'm not really sure that there exists a book that is so low-level as c# in depth for Silverlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Silverlight 4 in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182374) cover almost topics you want to learn even it's not much deep but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt c# from a book then went on to use Silverlight 4 for Dummies which is actually a really good and comprehensive guide. I can't remember if it had all the stuff mentioned above but it did have a large amount of it and about 2 months on after learning it I know my way around silverlight fairly well.